# Circular file inclusion C++

Tags: c++, circular-dependency

Say that we have two classes:

```cpp
// Object.hpp
class Object
{
    Handler* h;

    Object();
    void method();
};

// Object.cpp
Object::Object()
{
    h = new Handler();
}
```

```cpp
// Handler.hpp
class Handler
{
    void update(Object*);
};

// Handler.cpp
void Handler::update(Object* o)
{
    o->method();
}
```

How to link the four files without there being an inclusion error? I've tried all of the ways that I could think of and that I could find online.

Adding `#include` in both files will result in this error:

```
Handler.hpp: error: ‘Object’ has not been declared
         update(Object*);
                ^
```

If I add a forward declaration of Object in Handler i get this:

```
Object.hpp: error: ‘Handler’ does not name a type
         Handler handler
```

Including Object in Handler.hpp and forward declaring Handler in Object.hpp gives this:

```
Object.hpp: error: field ‘h’ has incomplete type ‘Handler’
         Handler handler;
                 ^
```

Meanwhile including Handler in Object.hpp an forward declaring Object in Handler.hpp gives this:

```
Handler.cpp: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Object’
     o->method();
      ^
```

I can't seem to figure out the way to include the files in each other. This structure is based on the decoupling component pattern from [Robert Nystrom's Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html). Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You do know that you can declare a class without defining it? class object;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c)

Comment: both ways of using a forward declaration should be fine. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, as mentioned in my question - I've tried forward declaring them, and got the errors that I've posted.

Comment: the errors refer to code that is not present in your example. Forward declaratiosn allow you to have pointers and reference, but eg not an object as member

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The errors you posted do not seem to come from the code you gave.

The problem with

```
Object.hpp: error: ‘Handler’ does not name a type
         Handler handler  //<-- Declaration of object of type Handler, not pointer
```

is that `handler` was declared as an object, not a pointer. Thus, the compiler needs to know the defnition. That is why a forward-declaration is not enough. If you add a forward-declaration of Handler in the Object.hpp you gave, it should work:

```
// Object.hpp
//forward-declaration of Handler
class Handler;

class Object
{
    Handler* h;

    Object();
    void method();
};
```

```
// Object.cpp
//include Handler.hpp

#include "Handler.hpp"
Object::Object()
{
    h = new Handler();
}
```

```
// Handler.hpp
//include Object.hpp

#include "Object.hpp"

class Handler
{
    void update(Object*);
};
```

```
// Handler.cpp
void Handler::update(Object* o)
{
    o->method();
}
```

Edited to add include in Object.cpp and remove first paragraph as per @TonyK's comment

Comment: And, for completeness, in this simple case the problem could also be solved with `class Handler* h;` inside the definition of `Object`. +1.

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong: you don't have to name your parameters in a function declaration.

Comment: Yes I don't need to name parameters in the .hpp. Your second paragraph is on the right track but adding an #include the the .hpp also gives an error. The code is correct, the problem is that one of the includes has to go in the *.cpp* file. Check my answer

Comment: @korajko True, edited to include the Handler.hpp in Object.cpp

Comment: Looking back at this problem, I think the dependency inversion principle would have helped a lot. Depending on common interfaces could help break the loops that are created when concrete classes depend on each other. (Can't be applied in all situations)

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Thank you all for taking the time to try and help me out and especially thanks to @Yksisarvinen for the helpful link.

The problem is that I have placed the #includes in the .hpp file, and this creates a problem for the compiler, even though I have include guards.

I solved this by using only forward declarations in the .hpp files that don't need any code from the included classes, and then added the #include into the **.cpp** files (where I use methods from the included class).

Basically I did the following:

- I added a #include "Handler.hpp" in Object.hpp (the Object class contains a Handler object, which calls the constructor which needs an #include)
- I added only a forward declaration of Object in Handler.hpp (Handler.hpp doesn't need any code from the Object files, it just needs to know that an Object class exists)
- And then finally I added the #include "Object.hpp" in **Handler.cpp** (Necessary because I use a method from Object)